# How to add type of property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have this code

```
type WithRequiredProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = Omit<Type, Key> & {
    [Property in Key]-?: Type[Property];
};

export type MessageWithMdEnforced = WithRequiredProperty<IMessage, 'md'>;
```

```
export interface IMessage extends IClass {
    rid: RoomID;
    msg: string;
    tmid?: string;
    tshow?: boolean;
    ts: Date;
}
```

The problem is that `IMessage` is imported from node_modules so I can not change in node_modules
And I want to add `errorReason: string` type in IMessage interface

Can Anyone tell me what to do ? How to achieve this ?

Comment: `interface IMyMessage extends IMessage` ?

Comment: There is nothing like IMyMessage

Comment: Not until you create it. Then it would exist and you can use it. Is that an issue? Because what you're asking for won't actually help you. Adding a property to an interface won't make any difference, since any existing consumers of `IMessage` won't access the new property. Any new consumers may as well just work with a new interface.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create new interface extended by `IMessage` so that the properties will be inherited to your new interface and use the new interface

```
type WithRequiredProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = Omit<Type, Key> & {
    [Property in Key]-?: Type[Property];
};

interface NewMessage extends IMessage {
    errorReason?: string;
} 

export type MessageWithMdEnforced = WithRequiredProperty<NewMessage, 'md'>;
```